# Minimum TLS issue connecting to SQL Server in R

Tags: r, sql-server, ssl, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to SQL Server in R (I have Windows 10 and am using R version 4.1.3) and when I try, I get an error message about my TLS version being less than the minimum version allowed. I'd like to update from TLS 1.0 to 1.2 but am struggling to find resources online that clearly lay out how? Any suggestions?

Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
odbcDriverConnect(paste("Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Server=",  :
```

> [RODBC] ERROR: state HY000, code 47072, message [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]**Reason: Login failed due to client TLS version being less than minimal TLS version allowed by the server

```
odbcDriverConnect(paste("Driver=SQL Server Native Client 11.0;Server=",  :
```

> ODBC connection failed

Comment: A number of components need to be installed, updated and configured to provide TLS 1.2 support, depending upon your client computer's operating system, installed SNAC/ODBC drivers and potentially .NET Framework versions. Best place to start is probably [KB3135244 - TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe)

Comment: Aside... SNAC (SQL Server Native Client) hasn't really been updated since SQL Server 2012 was released. You might have better success trying to use ODBC Driver 17 (or 18) for SQL Server.